# Simplify $\neg p \lor \neg(q \land r)$

Tags: propositional-calculus

How can I simplify the following logical expression by using the laws of logic?

$$\neg p\lor\neg(q\land r)$$

The answer given by my tutor is $q$ but it seems I can't figure out how to simplify it.

Comment: The simplified version, as it stands, depends on all three variables.

Comment: I am only able to simplify statement that have only 2 variable. However, when the expression has 3 variable, I am really lost.

Comment: No, but then you cannot simplify it further. The answer, as it stands, is $\overline{p} \vee \overline q \vee \overline r$, which can't be simplified further.

Comment: Agree. That's how i get. I think the tutor has wrongly wrote the question

Comment: Well, at least we have spotted it. That's good.

Comment: You may simplify it to $\neg(p\land q\land r)$. Looks kind of nice.

Answer (score 1):

$$\neg p\lor\neg(q\land r)\equiv \lnot p \lor (\lnot q \lor \lnot r) \tag {by DeMorgan's}$$

$$\equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor \lnot r\tag{parenthes not needed}$$

The above can not be simplified further.

Comment: Your tutor is/was wrong.